como realizar un trigger en tableplus
estoy intentando realizar un trigger en TablePlus (gestor de base de datos) pero no se como indicar al dato antiguo que se actualizo, para guardarlo en otra tabla.
he intentado con la tabla INSERTED y OLD, pero no funciona nada.
si alguien ha hecho algun trigger en esta aplicacion, les pido ayuda
lo que quiero hacer es insertar en la tabla2 los registros que se actualizaron de la tabla1

en mysql, los datos estan en old... TablePlus es tu ide?? no creo que el error venga por ahi, tal vez esta mal el trigger?

correcto tablePlus es el IDE, @gbianchi tienes algun ejemplo sencillo haciendo referencias a los datos nuevos y antiguos?

si.. tengo montones.. figuran en google.. podes buscarlos tranquilamente ;)...  si no vemos tu codigo, no sabemos que pasa...

en la primera imagen se muestra el trigger sin cerrar el if 
esto da como error la siguiente imagen, entendiendo que hace ver que falta algo por incorporar para que funcione el trigger.

luego cierro el if con un END (tambien trate con un END IF) arrojando el mismo error.


es mucho mas fácil realizar los trigger mediante código, pero en este ide no tiene esa función. se que esto es muy básico pero no logro encontrar el error.
